# Velocity : Turning off Strict mode in apache velocity

Tags: java, velocity, template-engine

How can I turn off strict mode in apache velocity ? Velocity will throw a MethodInvocationException for references that are not defined in the context. I need it to simply render nothing in that case.

How can I enable non strict mode?

Tried $!name, but this too throws error, if its not defined in context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have try

```
runtime.references.strict = false
```

For more info check this below link:
http://velocity.apache.org/engine/1.7/developer-guide.html